# Trigger a specific project inside a repository when creating a build in Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I have one repository with 3 branches dev, test and prod. I have a Visual Studio solution with 3 projects in it. One Angular, a worker service and ASP.NET web api project. So that whole solution in one repository.

I have pushed everything to dev branch. So when creating the build pipeline I chose ASP.NET core and then on writing the build yaml, in the trigger I specified Dev branch

```
trigger : - dev
```

But how can I specify which project to build among the 3 project in that repository to build? My plan is to build the ASP.NET core web api to build.

Also I need another build for the angular as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be in your [build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops):

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj' # Update this to match your need
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

The project path will be different for your various projects

Comment: Oh nice.. So it will build project in that path, isn't it? Awesome